# JQuery Context Menu integration with JQuery DataTable

Tags: javascript, jquery, contextmenu, datatables

I can't make Context Menu working. What I want is when I clicked any row, it alert me the first td text in it.

This is my code in initializing my dataTable:

```
var init_item_seized_tbl = function init_item_seized_tbl(){
    $('#item_seized_tbl').DataTable({
        "autoWidth": false,
        "aoColumnDefs": [
            { "bSortable": false, "aTargets": [ 4 ] },
            { "sWidth": "20%", "aTargets": [ 0 ] },
            { "sWidth": "40%", "aTargets": [ 1 ] },
            { "sWidth": "10%", "aTargets": [ 2 ] },
            { "sWidth": "20%", "aTargets": [ 3 ] },
            { "sWidth": "10%", "aTargets": [ 3 ] },
        ],
        "fnCreatedRow"  : function( nRow, aData, iDataIndex ){
            $(nRow).addClass('item-context');
        },
        "fnRowCallback" : function( nRow, aData, iDisplayIndex, iDisplayIndexFull){
            console.log('fnRowCallback');
            $('table#item_seized_tbl tr').on('mouseenter', function () {       
                $(this).contextMenu({
                    selector: '.item-context',
                    callback: function(key, options) {
                        //var m = "clicked: " + key;
                        //window.console && console.log(m) || alert(m);
                    },
                    items: {
                        "edit": {name: "Edit", icon: "edit"},
                        "cut": {name: "Cut", icon: "cut"},
                        "copy": {name: "Copy", icon: "copy"},
                        "paste": {name: "Paste", icon: "paste"},
                        "delete": {name: "Delete", icon: "delete"},         
                    }
                },
                function (action, el, pos) {
                    alert(
                        'Action: ' + action + '\n\n' +
                        'Element ID: ' + $(el).attr('id') + '\n\n' +
                        'X: ' + pos.x + '  Y: ' + pos.y + ' (relative to element)\n\n' +
                        'X: ' + pos.docX + '  Y: ' + pos.docY + ' (relative to document)\n\n'               
                    );  
                }
                );
            });     
        }
    });
}
```

The problem is the context menu is not appearing.

I tried another approach by separating the initialization of context menu. But I have no idea how to handle the events and alert me the first td in a row.

```
$.contextMenu({
    selector: '.item-context',
    callback: function(key, options) {
        var m = "clicked: " + key;
        window.console && console.log(m) || alert(m);
    },
    items: {
        "edit": {name: "Edit", icon: "edit"},
        "cut": {name: "Cut", icon: "cut"},
        "copy": {name: "Copy", icon: "copy"},
        "paste": {name: "Paste", icon: "paste"},
        "delete": {name: "Delete", icon: "delete"},         
    }
});
```

Your responses would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe you are making it too complicated? Cannot see why you should initialize the context menu in `fnRowCallback` and not sure you actually need an "action". The following works right away :

```
$.contextMenu({
    selector: '#example tbody td',
    callback: function(key, options) {
       var cellIndex = parseInt(options.$trigger[0].cellIndex),
           row = table.row(options.$trigger[0].parentNode),
           rowIndex = row.index();

        switch (key) {
           case 'edit' :
               //edit action here
               break;
           case 'cut' :
               //cut action here
               break;
           //...
           case 'delete' :
               table.cell(rowIndex, cellIndex).data('').draw();
               break;
           default :
               break;
       }               
    },
    items: {
        "edit": {name: "Edit", icon: "edit"},
        "cut": {name: "Cut", icon: "cut"},
        "copy": {name: "Copy", icon: "copy"},
        "paste": {name: "Paste", icon: "paste"},
        "delete": {name: "Delete", icon: "delete"},         
    }
});
```

demo -> **http://jsfiddle.net/w0p6jz0n/**

The type of action is found in `key`. The element in focus for the active contextMenu is found in `options.$trigger[0]`. Now we can find

- the cellIndex (which column) by `options.$trigger[0].cellIndex`
- the underlying dataTables row by `table.row(options.$trigger[0].parentNode)`
- the *real* rowIndex (which is important since the dataTable propably is sorted) by `row.index()`

By that it is easy to work on the cells that the user triggers the contextMenu on. As the delete example above :

```
case 'delete' :
   table.cell(rowIndex, cellIndex).data('').draw();
   break;
```

‑ deletes the content of the cell.

Comment: I will definitely try this. I'll get back to you and mark this as answer if your answer worked. Thanks

Comment: it says table.row is not a function. I assigned table = $('table-id'). So how can I solve this?

Comment: @JCFrane,  you can get " table.row is not a function" if you have initialized with dataTable() lowercase d. Or if table not is a global variable and you try to use in a local scope context.